# How I can see application information even if QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission isn't added in AndroidManifes.xml File

Tags: android

As specified here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en#zippy=%2Cinvalid-uses%5D We should have QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission in AndroidManifest.xml if we wanna have information about all installed apps on android device. Though I remove this permission from AndroidManifest file, I can able to get that information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Android 11, [Package visibility filtering](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) is introduced. The more [use cases](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases) for the Package visibility.

With the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission user can get all the apps regardless of the package visibility declared in the `manifest.xml` file. *Allows query of any normal app on the device, regardless of manifest declarations.*

These changes affect apps only if they target Android 11.